# android RadioButton issue in android 4

Tags: android, radio-button

I have a simple application. The screen is build inside a RelativeLayout. I have more 
LinearLayout(s), one of them shows the 2 RadioButton(s), like this:

```
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="3dp" android:gravity="center">
            <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/rgrDayToReport" 
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RadioButton android:checked="true" android:id="@+id/rbtnToday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="@string/radioTodayText"/>
                <RadioButton  android:id="@+id/rbtnYesterday"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:text="@string/radioYesterdayText"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>
```

This panel render correctly in any device (as I did tests) except Samsung Galaxy s3. On this device (only on this device) the screen looks like this:

[image]

**How should I fix this?**

Comment: Can you maybe show an image of how it should be (considering you said you've done tests on other devices)? Because I don't really understand what is wrong..

Comment: @ndsmyter well, its clear that the text is overlapping the `RadioButtons'` images.

Comment: On the other devices the text is on left of the circle. Normal RadioButton render.

Comment: Ah, stupid remark.. I think this is probably not something you can solve programmatically. But maybe you can contact Samsung for this, because I think this is probably just a bug in the Galaxy S3 if you say it works good on all other devices

Comment: Looks like it has to do with the customized themes vendors use to replace the default ones with.Also, you can try setting theme to `device-default` and see if that fixes this.

Comment: See possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247922/radio-button-text-over-button/17021805#17021805

Answer (score 15):

I was experiencing the same problem. I have solved this by NOT setting `paddingLeft` on RadioButtons and CheckBoxes - leaving default value. `paddingLeft` was counted from the drawable on all phones and from left corner on Galaxy S3. Also setting `background` was causing the same bug on Galaxy S3. After leaving default values it's now usable everywhere.

Comment: As you can see in my code, there are no padding or background in my XML. And till the render is not correct.

Comment: I know, I'm just posting this because it can be related.

Comment: Setting a custom state-list drawable as background for the radio buttons was causing the text to overlap on the check box for me. Interestingly this was reproducible on my Samsung tab2, Sony Exp Z but neither on Nexus 4 nor on emulators.

Comment: I really hate Samsung for corrupting Android with their flaws... I've wasted so much time trying to solve this issue. BTW the bug is also present in the original Samsung Galaxy (samsung_sgh_t959v).

Comment: Samsung is the Internet Explorer of Android Devices.

Answer (score 5):

This might be too late, but i had the same problem and it was solved by specifying a `android:drawableRight` or `android:drawableLeft`, instead of `android:button` which is set by default

Answer (score 0):

Testing on a Rugby Pro and a GS5, I found that if you want to set the background color, you have to do it in the java, rather than in the XML. If you do it in XML, Samsung devices have an issue and cause the overlap.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this by setting the `paddingLeft` of the `RadioButton` to some value that made it look proper. I've only tested this on my Samsung device and not any other devices so I'm not sure what that will look like on your devices that "worked".

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if I do that then I'll have a normal look in S3 and a extra space in all the other devices. This is not a working solution, I thought to this by myself too.

Comment: I tested my proposed solution on a Verizon Galaxy S3, a Galaxy Tab, and a Nexus S and everything looks perfectly fine. Maybe this would work for your case as well.